# Calling an attribute or function of a variable obtained through a template filter

Tags: django, django-templates

This is what I want to write:

```
categories|last.translated_name
```

Where categories is a list of Category objects and translated_name is a function in the Category class.

This is the error when the above invalid syntax is used:

> Could not parse the remainder:
>   '.translated_name' from
>   'categories|last.translated_name'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% with categories|last as last_category %}
    {{ last_category.translated_name }}
{% endwith %}
```